# Return a pointer from RCU-protected list in LKM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rcu

I'm a bit confused about such code:

```c
struct a {
    // ...
    struct list_head some_list;
    // ...
};

struct e {
    struct list_head next;
    // ... 
};

static void *traverse(struct a *a)
{
    struct e *e;
    
    rcu_read_lock();
    list_for_each_entry_rcu(e, &a->some_list, next) {
        if (...) {
            rcu_read_unlock();
            return e;
        }
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    return NULL;
}
```

In the function `traverse` we take a lock `rcu_read_lock` and then iterate over some list until some condition is met, but after this condition is met we unlock `rcu_read_unlock` RCU and return the `e` pointer.

The key point that is confusing me is that we unlock RCU read-side critical section, but keep pointer from the list, what if write-side will remove this element and it seems that this pointer `e` will be broken, isn't it?

AFAIK, the pointer is valid only inside read-side critical section, i.e. between `rcu_read_lock` and `rcu_read_unlock`, am I wrong?

P.S.: `traverse` is called without holding any locks.

Comment: in typical cases, code that has a pointer to such a struct does a "get" to increase its reference count so it will not be deleted until the corresponding "put"

Comment: You're right, but here I don't have such a counter, so it's interesting for me is there a bug in such a code

Comment: Is there some real code in the kernel that does this?

Comment: Actually there isn't. This code is not from the kernel itself

Comment: Or even if there is I guess as @MarcoBonelli mentioned it is safe for such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are right, the snippet of code you posted seems "broken". What you usually want to do in such a situation is something like the following:

```c
static void traverse(struct a *a, void (*callback)(struct e *))
{
    struct e *e;
    
    rcu_read_lock();
    list_for_each_entry_rcu(e, &a->some_list, next) {
        if (...) {
            callback(e);
            break;
        }
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
}
```

This way you can ensure that whatever operation you need to perform on `e`, the `callback()` function that gets called to use it will see a consistent version of the list (of course, assuming that it does not save `e` somewhere to use it later, otherwise we're back at square one).

Doing `return e;` after `rcu_read_unlock();` can cause trouble as you have noted in your question, but in theory it *could still be fine* depending on the exact scenario. Whether there's a problem or not only depends on what is done with `e` after it is returned.

For example, if `e` is simply checked in the caller with something like `if (e != NULL) {...}` then that'd be fine. Of course though, one could argue that you could have just made the `traverse` function return a `bool` in such case :')